# Is there a way to loop through and execute all of the functions in a Python class?

Tags: python, reflection, class

I have

```
class Foo():
    function bar():
        pass

    function foobar():
        pass
```

Rather than executing each function one by one as follows:

```
x = Foo()
x.bar()
x.foobar()
```

is there a built-in way to loop through and execute each function in the sequence in which they are written in the class?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.  You can access `Foo.__dict__`, and call each value in turn (catching errors for non-callable members), but the order is not preserved.

```
for callable in Foo.__dict__.values():
    try:
        callable()    
    except TypeError:
        pass
```

This assumes none of the functions take parameters, as in your example.

Answer (score 13):

```
def assignOrder(order):
  @decorator
  def do_assignment(to_func):
    to_func.order = order
    return to_func
  return do_assignment

class Foo():

  @assignOrder(1)
  def bar(self):
    print "bar"

  @assignOrder(2)
  def foo(self):
    print "foo"

  #don't decorate functions you don't want called
  def __init__(self):
    #don't call this one either!
    self.egg = 2

x = Foo()
functions = sorted(
             #get a list of fields that have the order set
             [
               getattr(x, field) for field in dir(x)
               if hasattr(getattr(x, field), "order")
             ],
             #sort them by their order
             key = (lambda field: field.order)
            )
for func in functions:
  func()
```

That funny `@assignOrder(1)` line above `def bar(self)` triggers this to happen:

```
Foo.bar = assignOrder(1)(Foo.bar)
```

`assignOrder(1)` returns a function that takes another function, changes it (adding the field `order` and setting it to `1`) and returns it. This function is then called on the function it decorates (its `order` field gets thus set); the result replaces the original function.

It's a fancier, more readable and more maintainable way of saying:

```
  def bar(self):
    print "bar"
  Foo.bar.order = 1
```

Comment: Try not to use `eval` if possible. Something like this should work: `[getattr(x, field) for field in dir(x) if hasattr(getattr(x, field), 'order')]`

Comment: I knew there had to be a better way :)

Comment: This is nearly exactly what I was looking for but I'm having some trouble with it. line 195, in decorator
    evaldict = func.func_globals.copy()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'func_globals'

Comment: @user3467349 That doesn't seem to have anything to do with what I wrote :/

Comment: The @decorator isn't the method of the decorator module? Anyways i copied the code exactly in python 2.7. hasattr(getattr(x, 'foo'), "order") False

Comment: This doesn't work for me! Is this compatible with Python 2.7?

Comment: @badp Nothing happens when I C/P your code in Python. However, if I remove [at]decorator in the assignOrder function this will work! So, for instance this is what I'm using now:
`def assign_order(order):
    def orders_decorator(to_func):
        to_func.__order__ = order
        return to_func

    return orders_decorator`

Answer (score 5):

Since Python stores the methods (and other attributes) of a class in a dictionary, which is fundamentally unordered, this is impossible.

If you don't care about order, use the class's `__dict__`:

```
x = Foo()
results = []
for name, method in Foo.__dict__.iteritems():
    if callable(method):
        results.append(method(x))
```

This also works if the function takes extra parameters - just put them after the instance of the class.

Comment: Any way to do it if I don't care about the order?

Answer (score 1):

So long as you're only interested in Python 3.x (and from the empty parentheses in your class statement I'll guess you might be), then there is actually a simple way to do this without decorators: Python 3 allows you to provide your own dictionary like object to use while the class is defined.

The following code is from PEP3115 except for the last couple of lines which I added to print out the methods in order:

```
# The custom dictionary
class member_table(dict):
  def __init__(self):
     self.member_names = []

  def __setitem__(self, key, value):
     # if the key is not already defined, add to the
     # list of keys.
     if key not in self:
        self.member_names.append(key)

     # Call superclass
     dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)

# The metaclass
class OrderedClass(type):

   # The prepare function
   @classmethod
   def __prepare__(metacls, name, bases): # No keywords in this case
      return member_table()

   # The metaclass invocation
   def __new__(cls, name, bases, classdict):
      # Note that we replace the classdict with a regular
      # dict before passing it to the superclass, so that we
      # don't continue to record member names after the class
      # has been created.
      result = type.__new__(cls, name, bases, dict(classdict))
      result.member_names = classdict.member_names
      return result

class MyClass(metaclass=OrderedClass):
  # method1 goes in array element 0
  def method1(self):
     pass

  # method2 goes in array element 1
  def method2(self):
     pass

x = MyClass()
print([name for name in x.member_names if hasattr(getattr(x, name), '__call__')])
```

Answer (score 1):

There is probably one of the shortest methods (the class name is *C*):

```
for func in filter(lambda x: callable(x), C.__dict__.values()):
    pass # here func is the next function, you can execute it here
```

The *filter* expression returns all functions of the class C.

OR in one line:

```
[func() for func in filter(lambda x: callable(x), C.__dict__.values())]
```

You can order somehow the functions, for example, by lexicographical order of their names by little more complex expression.

Comment: `c = C(); [f(c,*arg) for f in C.__dict__.values() if callable(f)]`

Answer (score 1):

This works and preserves the order:

```
class F:

    def f1(self, a):
        return (a * 1)

    def f2(self, a):
        return (a * 2)

    def f3(self, a):
        return (a * 3)

    allFuncs = [f1, f2, f3]

def main():
    myF = F()
    a = 10
    for f in myF.allFuncs:
        print('{0}--> {1}'.format(a, f(myF, a)))
```

The output would be:

```
10--> 10
10--> 20
10--> 30
```

**Note:** The advantage of using this instead of `F.__dict__.values()` is that here you can have a list of those functions that you prefer to be called, and not necessarily all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing an issue which is related to yours but, might help others for the same situation as I have faced.

> ### What I was trying:

I was learning `datetime` module in python and created an object of that. Now, to get the details from that object, I needed to manually you know, press the *Tab* key, get list of available methods/attributes and then type them and finally then after get the result. And needed to repeat for other times too!

> ### What I needed:

Since there was a mixture of Methods (which are callable) and Attribute (which can't be called) I needed to automate all of them to be used or called (se) and see their result in just a single loop.

> ### What I tried:

I just made a simple looking *for* loop which iterates over `dir(datetimeobj)`... Let me show you how...

```
# Creating an Obj
date = datetime.datetime(2020,1,29,12,5)

# Printing (But won't work, discussing 'why' in a bit)
for method in dir(date):
    if callable(method):
        print(f"{method}() -->  {date.method()}")
    else:
        print(f"{method}   -->  {date.method}")
```

Looks fine, right! It should work... but, no - it won't.
Executing this code will result in error...

*##Error:* **'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'method'**

---

> ### The Problem:

Aha! We are trying to call `method` which is the string so, `date.method()` / `date.method` is invalid.

> ### Towards Solution:

I will try not to discuss so long here... as the code given is self-explanatory, but just see this...

```
dir_without_dunders = [method for method in dir(date) if not method.startswith('_')]

for method in dir_without_dunders:
    RealMethod = eval(f'date.{method}')
    try:
        if callable(RealMethod):
            print(f"{method}() -->  {RealMethod()}")
        else:
            print(f"{method} --> {RealMethod}")
    except:
        continue
```

Code summary: 
• Created `dir_without_dunders` for you know... 
• Took another variable `RealMethod` because `method` will be having the string (name) just to make printing more clear and sensible 
• The main solution is with `eval(f'date.{method}')` *that is the hack*. 
• Why used `try` block? - It is because not all methods can be called without any parameters and they needed different set and number of parameters, so I called only those which can be called simply!

That's it.
Works for this datetime object calls as it has majority of methods with empty set of parameters.