# Python - Register functions from imported module

Tags: python, function, module, decorator

I'm trying to determine the best way to implement my application where there will be a main program (main.py) and a separate rules module (rules.py) where an arbitrary number of rules can be written and they will all be applied in main.py to manipulate some data (a dictionary).  A user of the application could add their custom rules in rules.py without impacting the logic in main.py.

I was thinking decorators would be useful here to register each function in rules.py in a way that main.py could iterate over them, but I'm not certain of the exact implementation.  Here is my skeleton code.

**main.py**

```
import rules

modifiers = [] # List of fuctions to modify data

def add_modifier(f):
  modifiers.append(f)
  return f

def invoke_modifiers(data):
  for modifier in modifiers:
    data = modifier(data)
  return data

if __name__ == "__main__":
  data = {'foo': 'bar'}
  print(f"Invoking modifiers on data: {data}")
  data = invoke_modifiers(data)
  print(f"Done invoking modifiers: {data}")
```

**rules.py**

```
from main import add_modifier

@add_modifier
def mod1(data):
  data['foo'] = 'baz'
  return data

@add_modifier
def mod2(data):
  data['quz'] = 'qux'
  return data
```

But when I execute the code, it doesn't modify my data.

```
$ python main.py
Invoking modifiers on data: {'foo': 'bar'}
Done invoking modifiers: {'foo': 'bar'}
```

So my questions are two-fold:

1. Is this a good way to go about having user-defined functions outside of the main application?
2. What needs to change to get the data to be modified by mod1 and mod2 in the rules.py module?

**EDIT**

If I omit the `from main import add_modifier` in rules.py, I get the following during execution:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import rules
  File "/home/telorb/Python/registerTest/rules.py", line 3, in <module>
    @add_modifier
NameError: name 'add_modifier' is not defined
```

Comment: Looks like you have a circular import. This is probably throwing an error in your rules.py.

Comment: See my edit for the result of omitting the import statement from rules.py.  Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really that familiar with decorators, so perhaps someone else may be able to advise on this.

But considering what you're doing, I think creating a class for users to add functions to would  the have the functionality you're looking for.

Something this thread: [Is there a way to loop through and execute all of the functions in a Python class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597827/is-there-a-way-to-loop-through-and-execute-all-of-the-functions-in-a-python-clas)

One suggested solution does utilize decorators, so that may clarify how better to build out your structure.

Answer (score 0):

For now I'm going with a solution found here: [How can I decorate all functions imported from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39184338/how-can-i-decorate-all-functions-imported-from-a-file)

**main.py**

```
import types
import functools

modifiers = [] # List of fuctions to modify data

def decorate_all_in_module(module, decorator):
    for name in dir(module):
        obj = getattr(module, name)
        if isinstance(obj, types.FunctionType):
            setattr(module, name, decorator(obj))

def add_modifier(f):
  print(f"Adding modifier: {f}")
  modifiers.append(f)
  return f

def invoke_modifiers(data):
  print(f'Invoking {len(modifiers)} modifiers')
  for modifier in modifiers:
    print(f'Invoking {modifier}')
    data = modifier(data)
  return data

@add_modifier
def mod_main(data):
  data['xray'] = 'zulu'
  return data

import rules

if __name__ == "__main__":
  decorate_all_in_module(rules, add_modifier)
  data = {'foo': 'bar'}
  print(f"Invoking modifiers on data: {data}")
  data = invoke_modifiers(data)
  print(f"Done invoking modifiers: {data}")
```

**rules.py**

```
def mod1(data):
  data['foo'] = 'baz'
  return data

def mod2(data):
  data['quz'] = 'qux'
  return data
```

**`$ python main.py`**

```
Adding modifier: <function mod_main at 0x7fe69ce75160>
Adding modifier: <function mod1 at 0x7fe69ce75040>
Adding modifier: <function mod2 at 0x7fe69ce75700>
Invoking modifiers on data: {'foo': 'bar'}
Invoking 3 modifiers
Invoking <function mod_main at 0x7fe69ce75160>
Invoking <function mod1 at 0x7fe69ce75040>
Invoking <function mod2 at 0x7fe69ce75700>
Done invoking modifiers: {'foo': 'baz', 'xray': 'zulu', 'quz': 'qux'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Python import machinery is quite complicated, but in this case it is quite simple to explain why the original code does not work.

When `main.py` is invoked, its module name is `"__main__"` and not `"main"`. When `rules` is imported and in turn it imports `main`, a new module named `"main"` (no underscores) is created, which has its own instance of `modifiers`. You can easily check this by putting `print("modifiers id = ", id(modifiers))` to `add_modifier` into the main block.

I think the best solution here is to make a new module that manages modifiers:

**main.py**

```py
from modifiers import invoke_modifiers
import rules

if __name__ == "__main__":
  data = {'foo': 'bar'}
  print(f"Invoking modifiers on data: {data}")
  data = invoke_modifiers(data)
  print(f"Done invoking modifiers: {data}")
```

**rules.py**

```
from modifiers import add_modifier

@add_modifier
def mod1(data):
  data['foo'] = 'baz'
  return data

@add_modifier
def mod2(data):
  data['quz'] = 'qux'
  return data
```

**modifiers.py**

```
_modifiers = [] # List of fuctions to modify data

def add_modifier(f):
  _modifiers.append(f)
  return f


def invoke_modifiers(data):
  for modifier in _modifiers:
    data = modifier(data)
  return data
```

**Result**

```
azelcer@ZX80:~$ python main.py
Invoking modifiers on data: {'foo': 'bar'}
Done invoking modifiers: {'foo': 'baz', 'quz': 'qux'}
```